# Why finiteness problem of CFL is decidable?

Tags: context-free, undecidability, pushdown-automata, decidability

We know that every $CFL$ has infinite configuration space. Due to this equality problem is undecidable. But why finiteness property is decidable inspite having infinite configuration space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language generated by a grammar with no useless symbols/productions is finite if and only if there is no non-terminal $A$ so that $A \Rightarrow^* \alpha A \beta$. This is easy to check.

Comment: $ \Rightarrow^*$ means arrow $ \Rightarrow$?

Comment: But why equality isn't decidable in same logic?

Comment: @Net, if at least one of the languages is finite, it is possible. How would you check in case both languages are infinite?